# How can I change the I2C address of an Adafruit seesaw soil sensor by shorting the address jumper?

Tags: i2c, adafruit

I bought a few of these moisture sensors ->
https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-stemma-soil-sensor-i2c-capacitive-moisture-sensor.pdf?timestamp=1543968539

I have a few of them, so I need to change their I2C addresses in order to use all of them on the same Raspberry Pi.

The pdf I posted above says I need to short the AD0 or AD1 to increase the address by 1 or by 2.

[image]

What exactly does this mean?

Do I just need to apply a voltage to one of these to increase the address?

Is the required voltage 3.3V (same as Pi's logic level) or 5V?

How long does the voltage need to be applied for?

Does the sensor need to be connected to the Pi's 3.3V power supply while applying the voltage?

What happens if I go past the maximum address? Ex: I short AD0 until I reach 0x39 and then I short again? Should it reset to 0x36?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means you need to bridge the gap between the two metal pads of AD0 and / or AD1. Normally you would do that with a little blob of solder. If you bridge the two pads of AD0 you add 1 to the address, if you bridge the gap of AD1 you add 2. If you do both you add 3 to the address. But this really is not a P issue,,, If you need more help, I suggest you check with Adafruit (e.g. on their forum)

Comment: @Dirk thanks for the answer. And you're right, this is not a Pi issue. It was very late last night and I thought I was on the electronics stackexchange. Their website is very similar, lol. If you post your comment as the answer, I'll be happy to mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you need to bridge the gap between the two metal pads of AD0 and / or AD1. Normally you would do that with a little blob of solder.

If you bridge the two pads of AD0 you add 1 to the address, if you bridge the gap of AD1 you add 2. If you do both you add 3 to the address.